# Using stat(2) - Getting Inode Number and Hard Link Count

Tags: c

I'm having problems getting this information. I'm not sure how to access it. My current snippet of code that this would fall in looks as follows. Feel free to critique whats already there. Thanks.

```
DIR *directory;
struct dirent *fileEntry; 

directory = opendir(argv[1]);
if(directory != NULL)
 {
  while((fileEntry = readdir(directory)) != NULL)
   {
    int i = 0;
    char *filename[];
    filename[i] = fileEntry -> d_name; // Get filename
    // Get inode here
    // Get hard link count here
    i++; 
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

Have you checked out the manpage yet?  http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat  You should be able to access them through:

```
fileEntry->st_ino; /* inode number */
fileEntry->st_nlink;  /* number of hard links */
```

Comment: dirent dont includes the st_ino or st_nlink. there should be a variable of stat struct to access st_ino etc.

Answer (score 1):

You've got some non-idiomatic syntax here:

```
int i = 0;
char *filename[];
filename[i] = fileEntry -> d_name; // Get filename
```

Much easier would be:

```
char *filename = fileEntry->d_name;
```

Of course, you don't need the variable if you're just going to print the filename once and never use it again.

The `struct dirent` looks something like this:

```
       struct dirent {
           ino_t          d_ino;       /* inode number */
           off_t          d_off;       /* offset to the next dirent */
           unsigned short d_reclen;    /* length of this record */
           unsigned char  d_type;      /* type of file; not supported
                                          by all file system types */
           char           d_name[256]; /* filename */
       };
```

So to get the inode number, you'll do something similar:

```
int inum = fileEntry->d_ino;
```

Again, there's no real need for the variable if you're not going to use it again.

If you think the variable names improve the legibility of your program, than by all means leave them in.

```
while((fileEntry = readdir(directory)) != NULL) {
    printf("inode %d is for file %s\n",
        fileEntry->d_ino, fileEntry->d_name);
}
```

The `i++` is just there to make bugs for your program. Since the `int i=0` is at the top of your block, the variable `i` is re-initialized to `0` on every loop iteration, which is good, because your `char *filename[]` variable doesn't allocate any storage to contain more than one pointer. (It just declares `filename` to be an array of character pointers -- it doesn't set aside any storage for the array.)

**Update**

With my new understanding of what's going on, I've got a few suggestions:

If you want to create a single large array to hold a large string containing the data, you can do that. It'd be wise to allocate memory for the array using `malloc(3)`, so that you can `realloc(3)` the array inside the loop if you need more storage.

It will look something like this:

```
char *s = malloc(100);
s[0] = '\0';
int size = 100;
int pos = 0;
while (file = readdir(dir)) {
    int filenamelen = strlen(file->d_name);

    if (pos + filenamelen > size) {
        int newsize = size + 300; /* 256 + inode + links */
        if (newsize < size) {
            /* integer wraparound, big mistake */
        }
        s = realloc(s, newsize);
        size = newsize;
    }

    /* &s[pos] sillyness is to avoid re-scanning
       the array for the NUL on every filename */
    strcat(&s[pos], file->d_name);

    pos += filenamelen+1; /* leave NUL in string */

    struct stat sb;

    stat(file->d_name, &sb);

    int stats_len;

    /* terminate inode and link count with NUL */
    stats_len = sprintf(s[pos], "%ld %ld\0", (long) file->d_ino, (long) sb.st_nlink);

    pos += stats_len;
}

fwrite(s, pos, 1, SOCKET_FILP);
```

If you want to send data to the client incrementally, then you do not need an array to hold the data and you can begin sending data *immediately*, rather than waiting until you've parsed the `stat(2)` information for all the files.

It will look something like this:

```
while (file = readdir(dir)) {
    struct stat sb;
    stat(file->d_name, &sb);

fprintf(SOCKET_FILP, "%s\0%ld %ld\0", file->d_name, (long) file->d_ino, (long) sb.st_nlink);
}
```

The NUL bytes are there to give your client a chance to properly parse the filenames. They can't contain the NUL byte but they can contain all the other byte values, so this provides unambigious parsing.

The incremental approach is *far* easier because there is no real memory management to deal with. The standard IO interface handles it all. (I'm not 100% convinced I got the big giant string version correct. C string handling is subtle.)

Comment: The reason I was using the `int i=0` was because I am having the program enter a directory and gather this information from each file in the directory. It was a mistake on my part on the placement of that.

Comment: I see the merit in using your option of just printing it and throwing it away. This is just the way I'm used to. Not too fluent in C as of now.

Comment: Ah, do you need to maintain the data "outside" the loop?

Comment: Possibly. I'm doing a project with a client and a server and I'm not really sure of the relationship and how they need to work together. I am under the impression that the server launches and waits for the connection by the client. I think I have this part of the code down. Once the client connects, I'm having the server fork a child process to handle the request. The server opens the directory given by the child and gathers the information (inode...) for each file in the directory. I am then to put all the information into a string and write it back to the client.

Comment: Just thinking about it, seeing that the information needs to be saved to a string, I could probably have a string array and save the information for a file to the array, then increment the array so it is ready for the next file to be read. This would loop until the fileEntry is null. Does this sound like it could work? Is there an easier way to do this? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: An array of strings will do, but depending your criteria, a single string with newline as delimiter may work even better.

Comment: newline isn't a very good delimiter, as you could have a file named with _only_ a newline character. The ascii NUL character (byte value 0x00) is a far better choice of delimiter.

Comment: If its not too much to ask, what would the code for a string like that look like?

Comment: It's the first codeblock after **Update** in my answer. (Note that I haven't _tested_ it -- I just wrote it. :)

Comment: I cannot begin to express my thanks for all the help you've been. I'll try to implement this into my code, and with my better understanding of what is going on now, hopefully have it all figured out. If not, would you mind if I sent it to you (@sarnold) to look over at some point? 

Thanks again, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

To directly get the hard links count in a directory, do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
unsigned int getNumberOfHardLinks(char* pathToTheDirectory){
        struct stat* stForHardLinksCount = (struct stat*)malloc(sizeof(struct stat));
        stat(fpath, stForHardLinksCount);
        nlink_t numberOfHardLinks = stForHardLinksCount->st_nlink;
        printf("\n%u\n",numberOfHardLinks);
        return numberOfHardLinks  ;
}
```

For the inode number, you can just do:

```
fileEntry->d_ino;
```

in your code.